# php decode binary(16) ip from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have ip's stored in mysql in binary(16) format

in phpmyadmin, it looks like this:

```
4c44b817
```

how can i convert it to readable ip string ?

Thanks !!

Comment: if its hexadecimal, convert to decimal using echo hexdec('4c44b817');

Comment: i already tryed this, but the result is just "13"

Comment: for me its: 1279571991. What database/table are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) function that converts numeric IPv4 address representations to the dotted-quad strings, e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(0x4c44b817);
+-----------------------+
| INET_NTOA(0x4c44b817) |
+-----------------------+
| 76.68.184.23          |
+-----------------------+
```

There's also `INET_ATON()` that works the other way around, as well as `INET6_*` versions of both functions that work with IPv6 addresses.

Comment: this is probably what was wanted.